# test PermissionRequiredMixin raises PermissionDenied instead of 403

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

I am using django 1.10.5 and the PermissionRequiredMixin.
Instead of redirecting users to the login, I want to return a 403-error if they don't have the right permission.
In theory, if PermissionDenied is raised anywhere, the response-object should have a status_code of 403:

> The only exceptions that are not visible to the test client are Http404, PermissionDenied, SystemExit, and SuspiciousOperation. Django catches these exceptions internally and converts them into the appropriate HTTP response codes. In these cases, you can check response.status_code in your test.

From the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#exceptions

However, my tests stop on an exception django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
This is the simplest test.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from doingTests.views import ViewWithPermission
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class TestPermission(TestCase):
    def test_permission_view(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username="john", password="doh")
        permView = ViewWithPermission.as_view()
        rf = RequestFactory()
        request = rf.get('/test/')
        request.user = user
        self.assertEqual(permView(request).status_code, 403)
```

With this view.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class ViewWithPermission(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    permission_required="doingTests.add_mock"
    raise_exception=True
```

What permission is required is actually not important, random strings, custom permissions and builtin permissions all raise PermissionDenied.

Since there are so many variables here, I might just have missed something, e.g. permission_required needs a permission-object instead of a string (tried that).

---

I missunderstood the following, correction below:

But I'm starting to think this might be a bug, because testing for PermissionDenied Exception still raises an exception instead of passing the test!
Chaning the last line in test.py to:

```
self.assertRaises(PermissionDenied, permView(request))
```

---

It all works fine if handled correctly, which requires the with-statement:

```
with self.assertRaises(PermissionDenied):
    permView(request)
```

Doesn't raise exception, test passes. I would still like to test the error-code though.

Comment: Can you change your view class complete (whit all the methods)?

Comment: The class is complete without methods, though I did specify a `template_name` in my original project. Adding it doesn't change the exception-behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer that was posted in the question but works with pytest:

```py
def test_my_view_for_users_with_permission(self):

    user = UserFactory()
    path = reverse("my_view")
    request = RequestFactory().get(path)
    request.user = user

    with pytest.raises(PermissionDenied) as e_info:
        MyView.as_view()(request)
```

If `MyView.as_view()(request)` raises a `PermissionDenied` exception, then the test passes.

*The `UserFactory()` in my example is a `DjangoModelFactory` class defined in another file named `factories.py`*